# How can i zoom within a 3d plot in matplotlib using ipympl and jupyter notebooks?

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-widget

I can zoom when i use a 2d plot using the area selection tool with the mouse on the plot, but when i want to do the same on a 3d plot, the 3d plot is rotated.
Is this not possible in 3d mode or do i just use the wrong mouse button / keys?

I used the jupyter notebook with `%matplotlib widget`, after installing `ipympl` and restarting jupyter notebook.

Î tried it with qt5, but the zoom in the 3d plots is not possible, or at least i dont know how to do it.

Comment: Re Qt5. Shooting in the dark: Control+MouseWheel, have you tried that?

Comment: @gboffi This just zooms the whole Jupyter Notebook, not the plot.

Comment: @Christoph90 My answer was not a general one, it was focused  on OP's attempt to use the Qt5 backend (it starts with "Re Qt5"…).